# Is it possible to insert a value into a BYTES column using SQL INSERT?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Here's my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Library (
  Index INT64 NOT NULL,
  Data BYTES(MAX) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(Index);
```

Is it possible to insert into the `Data` column using an `SQL INSERT` statement?  I tried base64-encoding the data and passing it as a string, hoping Spanner would be smart enough to detect base64, but no luck.  Am I out of luck?  Will I need to write an app using the Spanner client library?

Thanks for any input/advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a `INSERT INTO (..) SELECT ..` in combination with for example the `FROM_BASE64` function. I'm not sure exactly which SQL client you are using in this case, but I just tried the following example using the latest version of [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/):

```
INSERT INTO Library (Id, Data)
SELECT 1, FROM_BASE64('BAR');
```

The latest version of DBeaver has built-in support for Cloud Spanner using the [open source Cloud Spanner JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-oss-jdbc).

Comment: @DanWebb Glad to hear it worked! Would you mind accepting the answer, so it's easier for others to find it as well if they have the same or a similar question?